# Turning 3 SQL queries into 1

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to get a list of calendars - some public some private. Access to the private calendars is managed through a bridging table that lists calendar id (ccalId) and user id (cuserId). I can achieve this but using 3 SQL queries.

Is it possible to achieve this using just one query? I have tried JOINs but it never seems to work.

```
    $calModel->where('calTeam',session()->get('teamId'));
    $calModel->where('calType','public');
    $calModel->where('calStatus','active');
    $data = $calModel->get()->getResultArray();

    $calUserModel->select('ccalId');
    $calUserModel->where('cuserId', session()->get('id'));
    $callist = $calUserModel->get()->getResultArray();
    $newarray = implode(", ", $callist);

    $calModel->where('calTeam',session()->get('teamId'));
    $calModel->whereiI('id', $newarray);
    $data2 = $calModel->get()->getResultArray();

    $data = array_unique(array_merge($data,$data2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: What Database is this? Can you provide, schema, sample data, and expected output. I cannot see any SQL Queries here.

Comment: This is an SQL builder in code igniter (php)

Comment: you missing a "from" clause! how are the tables related? `$calModel->whereiI` is a typo

Comment: I am using Models so I don't need to specify a from clause. The code above works. The question is whether it can be simplified

Comment: Its possible to simplify your code and make those queries in single query.
However as @SrinikaPinnaduwage said, please provide more information about your database.

Answer (score 0):

Not every time the codeigniter query builder is the best solution. In my opinion for more complex queries it is better to do direct query to the database, instead of using models.

You can easily do a query with 2 joins to get all the results without the useless data. That would work faster and would look cleaner in your code.